# Llamar funcion Javascript desde Controller ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Necesito ejecutar una **funcion javascript** desde mi controller de .net core.

Tengo un controlador el cual me genera dos archivos unos csv y otro xlsx, el tema es que como he consultado en internet me funciona solamente cuando llamo desde el el controlador index pero desde otro no me funciona , quien pueda ayudarme lo agradezco.

Código que me funciona hasta ahora es el siguiente:

en el html:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowGreetings(name) {
        alert("Name: " + name);
    };
</script>
@if (ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
                    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction)
    </script>
}


<div class="container">
    <br />
    <h1 style="color: #58b5db; font-family:Bahnschrift" class="my-3 mx-2"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload File</h1>
    <br />

    <div class="form-group col-12">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "UploadFile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <div class="row">
                <label for="file" class="col-1" align="right">File:</label>
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="form-control-file col-11" onchange="return fileValidation()">
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div id="msgError" style="color:red; font-size:18px; font-family:Bahnschrift;"></div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button disabled="disabled" id="btnUpload" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="cargarLoader()">Upload File</button>
                </div>
                <div id="loader" class="loader" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>

        }
    </div>
</div>
```

en el controller:

```html
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction = string.Format("ShowGreetings('{0}');", "jesus");
            return View();
        }
```

sin embargo cuando intento llamar la misma funcion javascript desde otro controlador que es donde estoy creando los archivos no me funciona, el codigo del siguiente controlador es:

```html
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Upload()
        {
            WSS_MP_AddressValidatorPortTypeClient wsUploadFile = new WSS_MP_AddressValidatorPortTypeClient();
            ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction = string.Format("ShowGreetings('{0}');", "jesus");
            if (Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Form.Files[0];

                if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
                {                    
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var fileNameAlone = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                    if (extension == ".csv")
                    {
                        var csvParserService = new CsvParserService();
                        var carpetaTemp = @"C:\Tmp";
                        string fullPath = Path.Combine(carpetaTemp, fileName);
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            file.CopyTo(stream);
                        }
                        var readFile = csvParserService.ReadCsvFileToEmployeeModel(fullPath);
                        if (readFile is null)
                        {
                            ViewBag.msgError = "The file structure is incorrect please verify";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Enviar archivo a servicio                           

                            List<string> stringArrayService = new List<string>();
                            foreach (var item in readFile)
                            {
                                stringArrayService.Add(item.IDSEQ +","+ item.ID_ENTITY + "," + item.ADDR1 + "," + item.ADDR2 + "," + item.CITY + "," + item.STATE + "," + item.ZIP);
                            }

                            var operationAdd = new mplt_MailPrep_AV_FileVal_Operation { IADD = stringArrayService.ToArray() };

                            using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(wsUploadFile.InnerChannel))
                            {
                                // Adding required Azure subscription key header
                                HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                                //Linea de seguridad AZURE 
                                requestMessage.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = "20b37b6673404435872ee14a2ec327eb";
                                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;

                                var result = wsUploadFile.mplt_MailPrep_AV_FileVal_OperationAsync(operationAdd).Result;

                                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                                var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
                                var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter);
                                csvWriter.WriteHeader<ArchiveCSVModel>();
                                csvWriter.NextRecord();
                                List<string> oADD = result.mplt_MailPrep_AV_FileVal_OperationResponse.OADD.ToList();
                                csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ArchiveCSVMap>();
                                List<ArchiveCSVModel> parts = new List<ArchiveCSVModel>();
                                ArchiveCSVModel temp = new ArchiveCSVModel();
                                //var archivo = new string[];
                                foreach (var data in oADD)
                                {
                                    var records = data.Split(",");
                                    temp.IDSEQ = records[0];
                                    temp.ID_ENTITY = records[1];
                                    temp.ADDR1 = records[2];
                                    temp.ADDR2 = records[3];
                                    temp.CITY = records[4];
                                    temp.STATE = records[5];
                                    temp.ZIP = records[6];
                                    temp.ADDR1_STD = records[7];
                                    temp.ADDR2_STD = records[8];
                                    temp.CITY_STD = records[9];
                                    temp.STATE_STD = records[10];
                                    temp.ZIP_STD = records[11];
                                    temp.MAILABILITY = records[12];
                                    temp.STATUS_DESC = records[13];
                                    temp.STATUS = records[14];

                                    parts.Add(temp);
                                    temp = new ArchiveCSVModel();
                                }

                                csvWriter.WriteRecords(parts);

                                streamWriter.Flush();
                                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                                //ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction = string.Format("ocultarLoader();");
                                //ViewBag.Loader("ocultarLoader();");
                                return File(memoryStream, "text/csv", fileNameAlone + "_" + DateTime.Now.Year + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "_" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "_" + DateTime.Now.Second + extension);

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    if (extension == ".xlx" || extension == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file.OpenReadStream());
                        DataTable Dt = ExcelPackageExtensions.ToDataTable(package);

                        List<string> stringArrayService = new List<string>();
                        foreach (DataRow dr in Dt.Rows) {                            
                            stringArrayService.Add(dr[0] + "," + dr[1] + "," + dr[2] + "," + dr[3] + "," + dr[4] + "," + dr[5] + "," + dr[6]);
                        }

                        var operationAdd = new mplt_MailPrep_AV_FileVal_Operation { IADD = stringArrayService.ToArray()};
                        //var operationAdd = new[]
                        //    {
                        //        new mplt_MailPrep_AV_FileVal_Operation{ADD = Dt.ToString()}
                        //    };
                        using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(wsUploadFile.InnerChannel))
                        {
                            // Adding required Azure subscription key header
                            HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                            //Linea de seguridad AZURE 
                            requestMessage.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = "20b37b6673404435872ee14a2ec327eb";
                            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;

                            var result = wsUploadFile.mplt_MailPrep_AV_FileVal_OperationAsync(operationAdd).Result;

                            byte[] resultFinally;
                            using (var createExcelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
                            {
                                var worksheet = createExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("FinallyAddress");

                                worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "IDSEQ";
                                worksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "ID_ENTITY";
                                worksheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "ADDR1";
                                worksheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "ADDR2";
                                worksheet.Cells["E1"].Value = "CITY";
                                worksheet.Cells["F1"].Value = "STATE";
                                worksheet.Cells["G1"].Value = "ZIP";
                                worksheet.Cells["H1"].Value = "ADDR1_STD";
                                worksheet.Cells["I1"].Value = "ADDR2_STD";
                                worksheet.Cells["J1"].Value = "CITY_STD";
                                worksheet.Cells["K1"].Value = "STATE_STD";
                                worksheet.Cells["L1"].Value = "ZIP_STD";
                                worksheet.Cells["M1"].Value = "MAILABILITY";
                                worksheet.Cells["N1"].Value = "STATUS_DESC";
                                worksheet.Cells["O1"].Value = "STATUS";

                                int i = 2;
                                foreach (var test in result.mplt_MailPrep_AV_FileVal_OperationResponse.OADD)
                                {
                                    int cont = 1;
                                    foreach (string word in test.Split(','))
                                    {
                                        switch (cont)
                                        {
                                            case 1:
                                                worksheet.Cells["A" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 2:
                                                worksheet.Cells["B" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 3:
                                                worksheet.Cells["C" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 4:
                                                worksheet.Cells["D" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 5:
                                                worksheet.Cells["E" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 6:
                                                worksheet.Cells["F" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 7:
                                                worksheet.Cells["G" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 8:
                                                worksheet.Cells["H" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 9:
                                                worksheet.Cells["I" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 10:
                                                worksheet.Cells["J" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 11:
                                                worksheet.Cells["K" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 12:
                                                worksheet.Cells["L" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 13:
                                                worksheet.Cells["M" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 14:
                                                worksheet.Cells["N" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            case 15:
                                                worksheet.Cells["O" + i].Value = word;
                                                cont = cont + 1;
                                                break;
                                            default:
                                                ViewBag("Error in request of service");
                                                break;
                                        }

                                    }
                                    i++;
                                }

                                worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();


                                resultFinally = createExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
                                return File(resultFinally, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileNameAlone + "_" + DateTime.Now.Year + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "_" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "_" + DateTime.Now.Second + extension);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            wsUploadFile.CloseAsync();
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si efectivamente tengo que retornar un archivo, sin embargo para la funcionalidad de la aplicacion se me hace necesario ejecutar un javascript desde este controlador, agradezco si me puedes colaborar como podría solucionarlo, Gracias.

Comment: No es necesario ir al servidor para crear una funcion script, debes separar la funcionalidad de la vista de la capa de negocio,es decir podrias hacer una llamada solo para obtener el nombre de usuario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una alternativa para mantener el **script** disponible a lo largo de **toda la aplicación** (Controladores y Vistas) es utilizar **variables de sesión**:

En el **Controlador** la asignas de esta forma:

```
HttpContext.Session["JavaScriptFunction"] = string.Format("ShowGreetings('{0}');", "jesus");
```

Y en la **Vista** la recuperas así:

```
@if (Context.Session.GetString("JavaScriptFunction") != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
         @Html.Raw(Context.Session.GetString("JavaScriptFunction"))
    </script>
}
```

Como estás utilizando **ASP.NET Core**, debes de realizar algunas acciones antes de poder utilizar Sesiones en tu aplicación:

**1)** Instala el paquete NuGet **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session** desde la Consola de administración de paquetes NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session
```

**2)** En el archivo **StartUp.cs** debes habilitar el uso de sesiones de la siguiente forma:

En `ConfigureServices(...)` añade el siguiente código antes de `services.AddMvc();`

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();  
services.AddSession(options => {  
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1000); // El tiempo de vida   
});
```

En `Configure(...)`

Añade antes de `app.UseMvc(routes => ..` el siguiente código:

```
app.UseSession();
```

**3)** Luego para acceder a la propiedad **`Session`** hazlo en el **Controlador** de esta forma:

```
HttpContext.Session["JavaScriptFunction"]
```

Y en la **Vista** así:

```
@{ Context.Session.GetString("JavaScriptFunction") }
```

Comment: eh seguido los paso sin embargo en el apartado Configure no me aparece esto "app.UseMvc(routes => .." ya que en mi StartUp aparece asi:

Comment: public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

Comment: dentro de este apartado Configure tiene este fragmento lo agrego antes del mismo y no funciona: app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

Comment: Que es lo que no te funciona?

Comment: cuando trato de llamar la session desde la vista me genera este error: "ISession" no contiene una definicion para "GetString" que acepte un primer argumento de Tipo "ISession" (¿Falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Comment: @WilliamAvella: Incluye en la Vista la referencia al ensamblado `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` al principio de la Vista.

Comment: si era eso, muchas gracias por tu apoyo y paciencia